# How I can solve "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" problem in my code?

Tags: unity, c#

It's simple turret rotating code. The problem is when the Player is destroyed by enemies, I get this error message below:
"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object LookAtPlayer.Start () (at Assets/Scrpits/Transform/LookAtPlayer.cs:15)".

I understand why I get this error, but somehow cannot solve it. All turret must look at the last position of the Player, I tried something but couldn't solve again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public float rotateSpeed = 2f;

private Transform player;
private Vector3 lookDir;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (player != null)
    {
        lookDir = player.position - transform.position;
        lookDir.y = 0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDir), rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this LookAtPlayer script is on each enemy GameObject and those enemies spawn at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your enemies are spawning even after your player is destroyed thus it throws exception as it couldn't find one and you're directly accessing transform of null object.

```
// Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        if(go != null)
        {
            player = go.transform;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it was as you said. Now I don't get the error. Thank you so much.